# Possible self join to get id of all matching columns

Tags: sql, linq, sqlite

Given a table in a sqlite database of
ID, Name, Value

The ID is not unique as it can have multiple names and values and not every ID will have the same names and values.

Now I need to query this table so I can find multiple matching names values pairs where they have the same ID.  Basically searching for the id that best matches the name values pairs.

e.g I need to find the id that best matches the following Name Values.

```
+---------+--------+
|  Name   | Value  |
+---------+--------+
| Product | Foobar |
|  Colour | Blue   |
+---------+--------+
```

from data like

```
1, Product, Foobar
1, Colour, Blue
1, Size, Large
2, Product, Xeon
2, Colour, Blue
2, Size, Large
2, Type, inline
3, Product, Foobar
3, Colour, Green
3, Size, Large
4, Product, Xeon
4, Colour, Blue
4, Size, Small
5, Product, Foobar
5, Colour, Blue
5, Size, Small
6, Product, Argon
6, Layer, 1
6, Colour, Pink
```

Not all items have the same names some are more some are less.

I may be open to restructuring if that would help and can query via LINQ

Comment: What does "best matching" mean?  Please edit your question to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can't you make Product, Colour, Size etc columns of your database? And then ID could be a primary key.

Comment: They cannot be columns as they are variable depending on the product, and more need to be added dynamically.  The table structure should not change

Comment: @user2903089 Seems like an XML style DB would be more appropriate for this sort of data. xpath could query this very directly. Might be worth considering in the future.

Comment: Could you expand on that please Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on CL.'s idea:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE (Name = 'Product' AND Value = 'Foobar')
                OR (Name = 'Colour'  AND Value = 'Blue'  )
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: Not quite I need to find what ID matches multiple name value combinations. SELECT ID from table WHERE (name= "Product" AND value="Foobar") AND (name="Colour" and value="Blue")

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Name in ("Product", "Colour") AND Value in ("Foobar", "Blue")`?

Comment: Both neat ideas thank you, The selection idea will be most suited. I have now been asked to be able to find values within a range as some dates in there as well.  The select can do that over the in, although I can see I can manage a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

This query first throws out any records that do not match your criteria, then counts the remaining matches per ID:

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(*) AS matches
FROM MyTable
WHERE (Name = 'Product' AND Value = 'Foobar')
   OR (Name = 'Colour'  AND Value = 'Blue'  )
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cecff/1)</kbd>

To get only the first result record, add `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Or you could add `HAVING matches = 2`

Comment: @Dan "best matches" might imply that a result is wanted even if there is no perfect match.